# How to add new column to a table in EF

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have added two fields to one of my models. I want to add this two column to its table in the database. when I add a new migration and update database I see this error:

> there is already an object named in the database

.. I clear all code migration and use the function migrationBuilder.AddColumn to add this two column. when I update database again I have this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'.

.. I do not know what is the problem?

Comment: Did you add them to the database first, then to your model?

Comment: Is there any import data in your database? If not, you could try to delete the database and add migration and update database for a quick fix. For error related with `migrationBuilder.AddColumn`, could you share us the related code.